# Fail To Get Microsoft Edge Window Icon

Tags: c++, windows

I am C++ developer. When I try to activate all the following Windows API functions on Microsoft Edge window handle I get `hIcon` 0, without error number (when activating `GetLastError()`).

```
SendMessageTimeout(hwnd, WM_GETICON, ICON_SMALL, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG|SMTO_BLOCK, 1000, (DWORD*)&hIcon);

SendMessageTimeout(hwnd, WM_GETICON, ICON_BIG, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG|SMTO_BLOCK, 1000, (DWORD*)&hIcon);

hIcon = (HICON)GetClassLong(hwnd, GCL_HICONSM);

hIcon = (HICON)GetClassLong(hwnd, GCL_HICON);
```

I do succeed to get any other application icon with at least one of those functions. Should I do something else for Microsoft Edge application?

Comment: Isn't Edge a Store app? I distinctly seem to remember starting it via an URL instead of as simple exe. Doubt ordinary window APIs will work.